# discord websocket stopped giving messages after certain period of time

Tags: node.js, websocket, discord, discord.js

I have implemented discord websocket to receive instant message. Everything goes well but after certain period of time, My log file stopped recording the messages. Sometimes after an hour or 2 hours but within 2 hours. When I rerun the node then it starts recording again. Not sure what is the issue.

```
const WebSocket =  require('ws');

const ws    = new WebSocket("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json");
let interval    = 0;

token   = 'SOME tOKEN';
payload = {
    op:2,
    d:{
       token:token,
       properties:{
           $os:'linux',
           $browser:'chrome',
           $device:'chrome'
       }
   }
}

ws.on('open', function open(){
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload))
})

ws.on('message', function incoming(data){
    let payload = JSON.parse(data)
    const {t, event, op, d} = payload;

    switch (op){
        case 10:
            const {heartbeat_interval}  = d;
            interval    = heartbeat(heartbeat_interval)
            break;
    }
    switch (t){
        case 'MESSAGE_CREATE':
             let author      = d.author.username;
             let content     = d.content;

             console.log(d);
                
    }
})

const heartbeat = (ms) => {
    return setInterval(() => {
         ws.send(JSON.stringify({op:1,d:null}))
    },ms)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything after the first line into a function. In the function, add this code.

```js
ws.on("close", functionName);
```

Put your function's name in place of the callback (no parenthesis). Outside the function, call the function. Hope this helped!